# Angular <-> firebase functions not sending back data trough GET request

Tags: angular, httprequest, google-cloud-functions

in my angular project I have:

```
this.htpClien.get(this.baseUrsl+"createEmployee",{params:{email:"sdfsd@dffdf.com",password:"sdafw22"}}).subscribe(sub=>{

  console.log("respons"+ sub)},error=>{console.log('error')}
```

and in my firebase functions:

```
exports.createEmployee = functions.https.onRequest((request, response)=>{

response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");

    if (request.method === 'GET') {
        let email = request.query.email;
        let password = request.query.password;

            admin.auth().createUser({
                email: email,
                emailVerified: false,
                password: password,
                disabled: false
            }).then(succes => {
                response.send(succes.uid)

            }).catch(er => {
                response.send(er)
            })
    }
});
```

User is created but I can not get response back to my angular project with userID and all I get is a error called in angular request ("console.log('error')).

I tryed to put that to my request in angular :

```
headers = new HttpHeaders();
this.headers.append('Allow-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
```

and then add "headers" to the request:

```
this.htpClien.get(this.baseUrsl+"createEmployee",{params:{email:"sdfsd@dffdf.com",password:"sdafw22"},headers:this.headers})
```

but that does not work att all and not even a user is created -guessing it is a problem with "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" but I looked trough all the answer on that topic here on stackoverflow and still can not figure this one out:S

Answer (score 0):

I finally figure that one out ,for anyone  having the same problem Yu have to specify response type so in my case it should look like this:

```
this.htpClien.get(this.baseUrsl+"createEmployee",{params:{email:"sdfsd@dffdf.com",password:"sdafw22"},responseType: 'text'})
```